# How to log error and throw exception in java functional programming

Tags: java, java-8, functional-programming

How I can convert the below pseudocode into functional programming?

```
public void someFunction(DataType value) throws CustomException
        if (check some condition on value){
                log.error("some log message");
                throw new CustomException();
        }
        if (check some other condition on value){
                log.error("some log message");
                throw new CustomException();
        }
}
```

As you see above, there are repeated *If* statements in the code and also every time the log and throw exception line is repeated. Also, I have multiple functions in the class having exact same format. Is there some way to change this above code into functional programming and get rid of repeated code and make it look cleaner?

Comment: this task contradicts the essentials of functional programming, hence it isn't suitable for it

Comment: You're probably looking for a proper extraction of logic. That doesn't necessarily mean FP - you can extract your logic into OO validators that you can even hook with AOP into your code to prevent the duplication of logic.

Comment: It's generally harder to implement FP logic in Java. In a more FP enabled language such as Scala, we use logging monads e.g. `treelog` to log, and option/either monads to handle exceptions.

Comment: How about using `check some condition on value || check some other condition on value` instead of repeating the `if` statement?